# Convert Property Types in Transformation

Tags: typescript

I have an array of raw data similar to the following with an interface for a corresponding type I want to use in my application:

```
const rawData = [
  {
    id: 122314,
    friends: 'A,B,C'
  },
  {
    id: 23342,
    friends: 'B,C'
  },
  {
    id: 412,
    friends: 'B,C'
  },
]

interface DataElement {
 id: number
 friends: string[] 
}
```

Note the real data set has about 15 other fields that I'd like to keep in place.

How can I go about transforming the raw data into the typed data? Everything I've tried so far ends up with a type error about `string` not matching `string[]`, since the types on friends obviously conflict.

Comment: Because friends in rawData is string, not string[]

Comment: I know that. I'm asking how can I go about transforming it from one to the other.

Comment: There is no direct solution for that like magical transformation. You can create a class and do the transformation inside the construtor.

You can do something like this... (I have not tested the code)

```
class DataElement {
   public friends: string[];
   constructor(public id: number, friends: string) {
     this.friends = friends.split(',');
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
 const elts: DataElement[] = rawData.map(d => Object.assign({},d,{friends: d.friends.split(',')}) as DataElement)
```

The `Object.assign` is to avoid mutating rawData during the transformation. If you don't mind, it can be shorter